# Hacer un método que visualice Holamundo en JAVA

Tags: java

Nos han mandado un ejercicio de crear con un método Holamundo. Tengo este código pero no me funciona... No tengo ni idea de la forma de tirar, ¿podéis corregírmelo? Por favor y muchas gracias.

```
    package tema2;

public class holamundo {
    public void holamundo(){    
        System.out.println("HolaMundopuntocom ");
    } 
    public static void main(String[]args) {
       holamundo(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/hola-mundo-en-java-con-ide-eclipse.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aqui lo tienes ;)

```
package javaapplication2;


public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void holamundo(){
        System.out.println("Hola Mundo");}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        holamundo();
    }

}
```

El problema en tu codigo es que no puedes llamar a un metodo no estatico desde uno estatico.